Which one is closer to $3024^{2500}$? $10^{8000}$ or $10^{9000}$?
I first approached this question by applying log to $3024^{2500}$.

$\log(3024^{2500}) = 8701.454467\cdots$

I then thought that since $8701$ is closer to $9000$, $3024^{2500}$ is closer to $10^{9000}$.
However, I observed that this argument may not be correct. Consider $10^2$, $10^4$, $10^5$. Although $4$ is closer to $5$, $10^4$ is actually closer to $10^2$. Hence, just comparing the indices may not yield the correct conclusion.
Back to the original question, can you suggest a way that we can determine the correct answer without using a computer (e.g. generating the exact value in a computer and find the difference)? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Your logarithm calculation shows that $3024^{2500}$ is less than $10^{8999}$, and this is alread closer to $10^{8000}$ (the difference between them is less than $10^{8999}$) than to $10^{9000}$ (the difference between them is $9 \cdot 10^{8999}$).
The number in the middle of $10^m$ and $10^n$ is $\frac{10^n + 10^m}{2} = 5 \cdot 10^{n - 1} \cdot (1 + 10^{m - n})$.
$$\log_{10}\left(5 \cdot 10^{n - 1} \cdot (1 + 10^{m - n})\right) = \log_{10} 5 + n - 1 + \log_{10}(1 + 10^{m - n}) \approx \log_{10} 5 + n - 1 + \frac{10^{m - n}}{\ln 10}$$
(the last approximation assumes $n > m$ and has good precision even when $n = m + 1$)

Without using logarithms, note that

$31^2=961 < 10^3$
$3024^2 < 3100^2 = 9610000 < 10^7$
$3024^{2500} < 10^{7\times 1250} = 10^{8750}$
$3024^{2500} - 10^{8000} < 10^{8750} - 10^{8000} < 10^{8750}$
$10^{9000} - 3024^{2500} > 10^{9000} - 10^{8750} > 10^{8999}$

so $3024^{2500}$ is at least $10^{8999-8750}=10^{249}$ times further from $10^{9000}$ than it is from $10^{8000}$.

Even this $10^{249}$ is conservative: it is more like $10^{298.5}$ times further

$$
\log\left(\frac{10^{9000}+10^{8000}}2\right)=9000-\log2+\log\left(1+10^{-1000}\right)\approx8999.6987+\frac{\ln(1+10^{-1000})}{\ln10}\approx8999.6987
$$
$$
\ln(1+x)\approx x \ \ \ \text{For small x and we can ignore} \, 10^{-1000}
$$
$$
8701.45<8999.6987
$$
So the given number is closer to $10^{8000}$

Denote $A = 10^{8000},B = 3024^{2500 },C = 10^{9000}$, as you already computed $\log B \approx 8701$, then:
$$\log\left(\frac{B}{A}\right) = \log{B}-\log{A}\approx 8701-8000 = 701 \implies B \approx10^{701}A$$
Then
$$B -A\approx (10^{701}-1)A$$
$$C-B\approx(10^{1000}-10^{701})A=\underbrace{10^{701}\underbrace{(10^{299}-1)}_{\gg10}}_{\gg10^{701}-1}A$$
We conclude that $C-B\gg B-A$, that is B is much closer to $A$ than $C$.
Remark: The ratio of distances $BC$ and $BA$ is
$$\frac{C-B}{B-A} \approx \frac{10^{701}(10^{299}-1)}{10^{701}-1}\approx 10^{299}$$

Your logarithm approach, directly in the posted question, is (by itself, with almost no further analysis) immediately conclusive.
To illustrate why, suppose $~0 < x < 10^4,~$ and you are trying to determine whether $~x~$ is closer to $~0~$ or to $~10^4.~$  The issue is reduced to whether
$$x < (1/2) \times 10^4 \iff $$
$$\log_{10} x < \log_{10} \left[ ~(1/2) \times 10^4 ~\right] \approx -0.301 
+ 4 = 3.699.$$

$8701~$ is clearly less than $~[ ~-0.301 + 9000 ~],~$ which immediately resolves the question.  That is, since you can immediately conclude that $~(3024)^{2500}~$ is closer to $~0~$ than it is to $~(10)^{9000},~$ you can then conclude that $~(3024)^{2500}~$ must be closer to $~(10)^{8000}~$ than it is to $~(10)^{9000}.$
The analysis in the previous paragraph critically depends on the preliminary conclusion that $~(3024)^{2500}~$ is in fact less than $~10^{9000}.$  However, this preliminary conclusion is implied by the fact that $~(3024)^{2500}~$ is closer to $~0,~$ than it is to $~10^{9000}.$
